# Transforming data from staging table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data (1 million lines) in a CSV file. I need to do a one-time batch upload of that data into some SQL tables, and then later, daily, an insert of a few thousand lines. I've already designed the data model so that the database is normalised.

I need to do some transformation on the fields, i.e., if a field in my csv has a certain value, set a flag to 1 in a table. What are the best practices to achieve this?

Another way I could achieve this is to read the CSV data in Python, handle all the data transformation in Python, and send the transformed data to my staging table. But I am wondering if it is better to do everything in SQL.

Comment: Are you open to use any ETL tools?

Comment: If possible, no. I am trying to keep the stack for this process as simple as possible, even at the cost of a loss in scalability and reliability

Comment: Then you an use Python, rather that any other ETL tools

Comment: Have you looked into "external tables"?  This requires the CSV file to be on the server, but then you can select from it like any other table and apply joins and expressions to transform the data.

Comment: If possible for you, Use the SQL*Loader

Comment: "even at the cost of a loss in scalability and reliability".  That's a rather scary thought . . . why on earth would you want a process that is not scalable and unreliable?

Comment: I'm lost.  If you want to set a value of a column in a table, then you want to do the work in the database.  In the end you'll need to do an `update` anyway, so you might as well do all the work there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tony Andrews suggested: you may want to have a look at EXTERNAL TABLES. To keep the following example relatively realistic, we {1} generate a .csv file which contains a million records.  Then, we {2} create an external table, and use this to {3} select and insert its data into a "destination" table, which, among other things, contains a virtual column (demonstrating how you could set a flag, which you have mentioned in your question).

You don't need to do steps {1a} and {1b}, as you already have the .csv file.

**{1a} Generating test data, writing .csv to disk**

```
create sequence uo_seq ;
-- all columns are (converted to) strings
create table somedata
as
select to_char( uo_seq.nextval )  oid
, object_name, status
, to_char( created )              created
, to_char( last_ddl_time )        last_ddl_time
from user_objects
  cross join ( select 1 from dual connect by level <= 1e6 )
where rownum <= 1e6 ;
-- Table created.
-- Elapsed: 00:00:10.286

SQL> select count(*) from somedata ;
"COUNT(*)"
1000000

set term off
set sqlformat csv
spool somedata.csv
select /*+ parallel */* from somedata ;
spool off
set term on
```

**{1b} check the generated .csv file (using bash)**

```
# head
$ cat -n somedata.csv | head -3
     1  "OID","OBJECT_NAME","STATUS","CREATED","LAST_DDL_TIME"
     2  "3111285","STRINGS_T","VALID","06-JUN-20","06-JUN-20"
     3  "3111286","RANDOM_STRINGS","VALID","06-JUN-20","06-JUN-20"
# tail
$ cat -n somedata.csv | tail -3
999999  "4111282","NEWTBL_ERR$","VALID","05-JUN-20","05-JUN-20"
1000000 "4111283","SYS_IL0000080492C00007$$","VALID","05-JUN-20","05-JUN-20"
1000001 "4111284","SYS_LOB0000080492C00007$$","VALID","05-JUN-20","05-JUN-20"
```

**{2a} Create a directory.**

```
-- On your (virtual) machine,  create a new directory eg
-- $ mkdir externaltables
--
-- copy your .csv file into this directory.
-- get your DBA to GRANT you the following permission:
SQL> grant CREATE ANY DIRECTORY to johnharrisons;
Grant succeeded.
--
-- Then, create a directory.
create directory external_tables as '/correnct/path/here/externaltables';
Directory created.
```

**{2b} Create an external table.**

```
-- notice: all columns are strings/varchar2, same as our .csv file
create table external_ (
  OID varchar2( 4000 )
, OBJECT_NAME varchar2( 4000 )
, STATUS varchar2( 4000 )
, CREATED varchar2( 4000 )
, LAST_DDL_TIME varchar2( 4000 )
)
organization external (
  type oracle_loader
  default directory external_tables
  access parameters
  (
    records delimited by newline
    badfile 'external_.bad'
    logfile 'external_.log'
    skip 1
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' missing field values are null
  )
  location
  (
    'somedata.csv'
  )
)
/

-- If you get any error messages when executing the SELECT,
-- check the logfile (external_.log) for clues -
-- you may have to tweak the "access parameters" a bit. Examples see:
-- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-03CE63AD-F046-4805-A560-E4CFD7FA8503
select count(*) from external_ ;
-- 1000000
```

**{3} INSERT ... SELECT ...**

With the external table in place, you can SELECT (and transform etc) and INSERT whatever you need.
eg suppose the DDL code of one of your existing tables looks like this:

```
create table clean (
  id number generated always as identity start with 1 primary key
, OID number
, OBJECT_NAME varchar2( 128 )
, STATUS varchar2( 128 )
, CREATED date
, LAST_DDL_TIME date
, flag varchar2( 1 ) generated always as (
    case
      when length( object_name ) > 6 then '1'
      else '0'
    end
  ) virtual
) ;

-- Notice that we are not inserting anything into the FLAG column.
-- Its values will be generated.
insert into clean ( oid, object_name, status, created, last_ddl_time )
select
  to_number( oid ) oid  -- explicit conversion VARCHAR2 -> NUMBER
, object_name
, status
, to_date( created, 'DD-MON-YY') created       -- explicit conversion VARCHAR2 -> DATE
, to_date( created, 'DD-MON-YY') last_ddl_time -- explicit conversion VARCHAR2 -> DATE
from external_
fetch first 12 rows only ; -- did not want to insert all 1000000 rows ...

select * from clean ;
-- result
+--+-------+--------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|ID|OID    |OBJECT_NAME   |STATUS|CREATED            |LAST_DDL_TIME      |FLAG|
+--+-------+--------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----+
|1 |3111285|STRINGS_T     |VALID |2020-06-06 00:00:00|2020-06-06 00:00:00|1   |
|2 |3111286|RANDOM_STRINGS|VALID |2020-06-06 00:00:00|2020-06-06 00:00:00|1   |
|3 |3111287|GETVARCHARS   |VALID |2020-06-06 00:00:00|2020-06-06 00:00:00|1   |
|4 |3111288|VARCHAR_T     |VALID |2020-06-06 00:00:00|2020-06-06 00:00:00|1   |
|5 |3111289|RNUMS         |VALID |2020-06-06 00:00:00|2020-06-06 00:00:00|0   |
|6 |3111290|SYS_C0012985  |VALID |2020-06-07 00:00:00|2020-06-07 00:00:00|1   |
|7 |3111291|ATTENDANCE    |VALID |2020-06-07 00:00:00|2020-06-07 00:00:00|1   |
|8 |3111292|STUDENTS      |VALID |2020-06-07 00:00:00|2020-06-07 00:00:00|1   |
|9 |3111293|ALLROWS       |VALID |2020-06-07 00:00:00|2020-06-07 00:00:00|1   |
|10|3111294|DATA          |VALID |2020-06-07 00:00:00|2020-06-07 00:00:00|0   |
|11|3111295|DATA_VW       |VALID |2020-06-10 00:00:00|2020-06-10 00:00:00|1   |
|12|3111296|UO_SEQ        |VALID |2020-06-11 00:00:00|2020-06-11 00:00:00|0   |
+--+-------+--------------+------+-------------------+-------------------+----+
```